# neo4j time-based relationships

Tags: time, neo4j, model, social-networking

I have no experience of/with neo4j and only came across it by chance so many apologies if my questions are trivial or even vague - I just can't seem to get my head around it though I did just find a book I'll read.

Basically, the problem is that of people that may or may not have had contact with one another over time. If one of those persons was of interest, Mr X, it would be useful to be able to query for those persons that Mr X has had contact with (and subsequently that they in turn have had contact with).

The data I have is essentially just a list of transactions showing the movement of people from one location to another, the date/time that they arrived and when they left, a bit like

```
{
    "pId": "1234",
    "location": "xyz",
    "start": "67764690000000",
    "end": "67764829800000"
}
```

I can't see how to make anything useful of data in that format but because I have access to it, I can change this so that it's split into two files, one containing every single pId (which uniquely identifies the person in question, along with some other properties); the other file containing what can be described as a list of "transactions", each transaction containing

```
{
    "pId1": "1234",
    "pId2": "5678",
    "location": "xyz",
    "start": "67764690000000",
    "end": "67764829800000"
}
```

This means persons 1234 and 5678 met/had contact over a period of time defined by the start and end date/time properties.

Is what I'd like to do possible? For example, A meets B, C meets B and D meets B. However, because C met B prior to B having met A (which is our "index case"), C is not of interest and so our contact network would consist of A meeting B and B meeting D.

At the moment, all I have and can do is load the separate csv files and run some very basic queries such as the persons that have had contact with a certain individual. Again, what I'd like is to be able to see which persons have had contact with a certain individual and which persons they in turn had contact with (which is why the sequence, or time, is important).

Any suggestions and help as to if this seems possible and how I need to go about solving this, and even if the data is in a usable format or not, would be greatly appreciated.